# If an update....Where affects no rows, are any locks created?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sybase

If I run a SQL statement like

```
UPDATE table
SET col = value
WHERE X=Y
```

And no rows match, therefore no rows are changed, are any locks created by the update?

The DBMS is Sybase + SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

If field `x` is indexed, then there will probably be a shared lock on that index while your `UPDATE` is checking it for matching records.

There should not be any row locks, but all locking behavior is contingent on your [server-level isolation settings.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can play with this script and see for yourself that sometimes locks are acquired and held even when no rows are updated:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Test
    (
      i INT NOT NULL
            PRIMARY KEY ,
      j INT NULL
    ) ;
go

INSERT  dbo.Test
        ( i, j )
VALUES  ( 1, 2 ) ;
GO

SELECT  @@spid ;

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE ;

BEGIN TRANSACTION ;

UPDATE  dbo.Test
SET     j = 3
WHERE   i = 3 ;

SELECT  *
FROM    sys.dm_tran_locks 
WHERE request_session_id = @@spid;

COMMIT ;
```

Answer (score 0):

In case an update statement is used which does not effect the records then an exclusive intent lock is being taken for the update statement while in transaction as first the rows effected are to be selected followed by the update on the table, however as there are no rows that need to be updated this intent lock is taken on the table for the transaction in an exclusive mode.